# Print Element Range Below Certain Value Using std::lower_bound()

Tags: c++, stl

I have an vector array which is populated with some double vector values. I want to print all digits below 2.0. My restriction, I have to use `std::lower_bound()`. How can this be done? Here's the minimal working codeI was trying to work with, however it gives only single values:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const double data[] = { 5.3, 9.2, 7.5, 6.9, 4.5 };
    const int dataCount = sizeof(data) / sizeof(data[0]);
    vector<double> vec(data, data + dataCount);
    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    auto less2 = lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 2.0);
    auto less4 = lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 4.0);
    auto less6 = lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 6.0);
    cout << "\nLess than 2.0 : " << *less2 << endl << "Less than 4.0  : " << *less4 << endl << "Less than 6.0  : " << *less6 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Regards.

Comment: The range needs to be sorted to use `std::lower_bound` correctly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I had mistakenly edited that bit, just reverted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [cppreference/lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound):

> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range [first, last) that is not less than (i.e. greater or equal to) value.

Therefore, if you want to print all elements below `2.0`, you need to iterate from `begin(vec)` to the iterator returned from `std::lower_bound`:

```
auto less2 = lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 2.0);
for(auto it = begin(vec); it != less2; ++it) cout << *it << " ";
```